# Objects in local storage are not rendering to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

I'm doing a watchlist application and i'm getting the data from an API and rendering the data to HTML with jQuery.

```
  const searchMovie = async (searchInput) => {
    try {
      const results = await obtainData(searchInput);
      let displayMovies;
      $.each(results, (index, { id, title, poster_path, release_date }) => {
        displayMovies += `
          <div class="col-md-3"> 
          <div class="well text-center">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${poster_path}"></a>
            <h4>${title}</h4>
            <h5>${release_date}</h5>
            <h6 hidden>${id}</h6>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id = "add-button" type="button">Add to watchlist</button>
          </div>
        </div>
          `;
      });
   $("#movies").html(displayMovies);
```

I have an 'on click' event to store the movie data to local storage when the button 'Add to watchlist' is pressed.

The data is succesfully stored in local storage but is not rendering to HTML.

I tried to render the objects(data) from local storage with this function, but is not working

```
  var data = localStorage.getItem('movieInWatch');
    if (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);

      $.each(data, (index, { id, title, posterPath, releaseDate }) => {
        $('#selected-movie').append(`
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <div class="well text-center">
        <img src="${posterPath}">
        <h4>${title}</h4>
        <h5>${releaseDate}<h5>
        <h6 hidden>${id}</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
        `);
    });
    }
```

This is how the data is stored:

[local storage data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDoyZ.png)

Comment: You've got a `console.log` statement in there, what does it report?

Comment: You have a function you are calling in a loop with `$.each`: Add logging inside it. Check what values the variables have. What does it report?

Comment: You're generating a template string and passing it directly to `append`. Store it in a variable first and log it. What does it report?

Comment: In short: **Do some debugging** and include it in the question (see also [ask]).

Comment: Aside: Heading elements (`h1`, `h2`, etc) are for *headings*. Not for font sizes or marking text as "important". If you have no content after a heading (before the end of its container) then you probably shouldn't be using a heading there.